# Run PSEXEC for every computer name in list

Tags: batch-file, remoting, psexec

I need to be able to run the following for every computer in a list on a txt file. The txt file would contain computer names, 1 per line and id need each line to be imported into the CompName variable. Below is what I currently have. The help is greatly appreciated.

```
:Start
@echo off

Set /p CompName=Computer Name:
Set /p BatName=Batch File Name:

md \\%CompName%.company.local\C$\ScriptFiles\
Copy  "\\Server-Name\Installs\Scripts\%BatName%.bat" "\\%CompName%.company.local\C$\ScriptFiles\Run.bat" 


psexec \\%compname% -i -h -s  "C:\ScriptFiles\Run.bat"

GOTO Start
```

Comment: Why would you just use the functionality of `PSEXEC`.  It has an option to read the a list of computer names and it also has a function to copy the batch file to the remote computer to execute it. `psexec @file -c %batName%.bat`

Comment: You know what I cant answer that question cause I had completely forgot about it. Thanks for the reminder, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A
```

Will give you a list of computernames. Put it in a file.

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A >> Computername.txt
```

Then type to do turned on computers

```
 wmic /node:@"Computername.txt" process call create "\\\\Server-Name\\Installs\\Scripts\\%BatName%.bat"
```

Comment: I need to be able to define these computers manually. They are particular users that use a specific program.